# Variables being overitten

Tags: java, variables

I have a piece of code that is giving me an unexpected output. I believe this has something to do with storage spaces as I described below under the output. But I am uncertain.

code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] x = {1,2};
        int [] y = plusOne(x);
        System.out.println(x[0] + " " + x[1]);
        System.out.println(y[0] + " " + y[1]);
    }

    public static int [] plusOne(int [] x) {
        System.out.println("x :"+ x);
        int [] y = x;//1 2

        x = new int [x.length];
        System.out.println("y: "+y);
        for (int i=0; i<y.length;i++){
            x[i] = y[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<y.length;i++){
            y[i] = y[i] + 1;
        }
        return y;
    }
```

Expected output:

```
1 2
2 3
```

Actual output:

```
2 3
2 3
```

From what I have find is that when assigning two integers. i.e. int x = y, this causes the x's storage place to be assigned to y's storage place since they weren't propperly initialized. But I am not 100% certain, what I have written here is all I could find.

Comment: Remove these lines in your code `for (int i=0; i<y.length;i++){
            x[i] = y[i];
        }` in `plusOne()` function, then you get expected answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `x[]` array in your method `plusOne()`.  Here is sample code which will achieve what you had in mind originally:

```
public static int[] plusOne(int[] x) {
    int[] y = new int[x.length];
    System.arraycopy(x, 0, y, 0, x.length);

    for (int i=0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        y[i] = x[i] + 1;
    }

    return y;
}
```

Here I copy the input array `x[]` into a new array `y[]`, and then initialize `y[]` to `x[]` plus one added.

The following code inside the `plustOne()` method is the source of your problem:

```
int [] y = x;
for (int i=0; i < y.length; ++i) {
    y[i] = y[i] + 1;
}
```

You assign `y[]` to point to `x[]` which exists *outside* the method call in `main()`, and then you dereference the array and increment its contents by one.  So the `x[]` array gets incremented by one, and also the method returns `x[]` incremented by one.

Comment: Thank you. Will give you the mark as soon as I can. But I have an additional question, why does the overide not work with single integers and strings but with arrays? I did some testing in eclipse.

Comment: The code you had will cause problems for any array AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int [] y = x;
```

to

```
int [] y = x.clone();
```

**Explanation**

To understand whats going on, add following statement on your main method

```
System.out.println(x+ ""+ y);
```

In first case, you'll see both x and y have same id because assignment operator simply assigns the reference to original array.

In second case, you'll see different id for x and y . Becasue clone() function creates copy of original array.